# How to move a Path in Graphics2D

Tags: java, graphics, awt

I am making a custom button with a shape on it. This shape can for example be a cross (as for closing the window). The class works like this: you create a button with a `Path2D` as parameter. This `Path2D` has been made by another class before. Now this shape will be painted in the center of the button by a custom paint method (overridden from `JButton`). This would be my code to get the coordinates of the top left point of the bounding rectangle:

```
Rectangle r = path.getBounds();
float x = button.getWidth() / 2 - r.width / 2 + x_offset;
float y = button.getHeight() / 2 - r.height/ 2 + y_offset;
```

I used these before and they work perfectly. Now as the method to draw a `Shape` on the screen is `Graphics2D.draw(Shape s)`, and you can't specify any coordinates, I want to know how I can change the x and y coordinates of the bounding rectangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not directly transform a `Shape` usually. But you can create a transformed copy:

```
Shape shape = ...
AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(dx, dy);
Shape transformedShape = at.createTransformedShape(shape);
```

Comment: You can also transform the `Graphics` context, just be sure to restore it when your done ;)